# Is there a way to add property to the mock object in Python unittest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to test the following code:

```
class ABC:
    def _check_something(cls, doc, doc_type=pqr.Document):
        return isinstance(doc, doc_type) and "xyz" in doc
```

A document is a NoSQL object. I am verifying if it is of certain instance and it has "xyz" in its key.

This is what I have got in its test class

```
class test_ABC(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.m_response = MagicMock()
        self.action.client = MagicMock()
        self.action.client.r_session.get.return_value = self.m_response

    def test_check_something(self):
        self.m_response.__class__ = pqr.Document       # Sets up the appropriate class for the mock up object.
        self.m_response.return_value["xyz"] = "test".  # Unable to add this key-value pair, hence test is failing on this point.
        self.assertTrue(self._check_something(self.m_response))
```

I am fairly new to the unit-testing. I tried couple of different ways mentioned in unittest documentation but nothing clicked yet. Is there a way I can add that property to the mock object which satisfies `"xyz" in doc` condition?

Please let me know if you need anything for the clarification.

Comment: You shouldn't be unit testing private methods, but you don't need a mock for that; just write a class that inherits `pqr.Document` and implements `__contains__`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can you help me with that, please? I am unable to get around my head after thinking so much. I have created a mess!